# Why do ham radio operators refer to current flow on the outside of coax as common mode current?

Tags: antenna, transmission-line

My understanding is that the desired mode of operation for a two wire transmission line is differential, where at any point along the line the addition of the voltage or current is zero, such that the electric fields cancel and net radiation is zero.

Due to skin effect, in coax, the two wires are the inside of the braid and the outside of the center conductor. Technically speaking in this case the outside of the braid isn't part of the two wire transmission line.

For transmission lines, if you add together together the voltage or current at any point along the line and then divide by two, the result is the common mode voltage or current, which is that portion which does not have an equal and opposite. Common mode current inside coax can only be caused i believe by irregularities in the physical properties of the coax, or if the transmitter output isn't exactly differential. Common mode current is not caused by antennas which aren't balanced.

For all antennas fed with coax, at the junction between coax and antenna, current flowing away from the transmitter towards the antenna, will, due to skin effect, split up between the side of the antenna connected to the braid and the outside of the coax. The ratio of current flow between antenna and outside of coax is directly proportional to the ratio of the impedance wrt ground of the antenna element connected to the braid and the outside of the braid.

If it so happens that the impedance of the antenna element is low compared to that of the braid, then most of the current will flow into the antenna.

Common mode current inside of coax and current flowing on the outside of coax are two completely different conditions. For differential systems, common mode refers to an error condition concerning two wires, the two wires in this case being inside the coax. Current flowing on the outside of coax is a direct result of the voltage divider which exists at the junction of the braid of the coax and the connected antenna element, and is not common mode current at all. The outside of the braid is effectively part of a single ended single wire circuit with ground as the common point.

So why do ham radio operators refer to current on the outside of coax as common mode current, when quite clearly it isn't ?

To me it seems they are getting the outside of the braid mixed up as part of the two wire transmission line inside the coax, and this just serves to confuse everyone.

Comment: "Common mode current is not caused by antennas which aren't balanced." that's certainly how most engineering references describe it.

Comment: The current isn't split between the antenna and the coax braid at the feed point.  The director and reflector in a Yagi have high currents and voltages on them, even though completely disconnected.  Same with a coax feed line.  It can pick up RF current even if disconnected from a radiating antenna (say powered by another feed or transmitter).

Comment: @hotpaw2 Then why do ham radio operators use a choke at the feed point ... ?

Comment: There are more differentials at play at the feed point than the split between the antenna and the coax.

Comment: One of your misconceptions here is that the antenna is an entity that acts alone by itself.  It is not.  You have to consider the entire antenna system, which includes the antenna, any reflectors around it, the coax, ground radials, the ground itself, and possibly even the structure the antenna is attached to.  Any imbalance anywhere in the antenna system or between parts in the system could cause common mode current.

Comment: To take this further, if the radio doesn't have a way to block common mode current at its output, then the radio (and its case) can have common mode current, and become part of the antenna system.  This is where the real danger lies, as if your radio case is radiating, you can get RF burns.

Comment: I wonder the opposite: Why do ham radio operators refer to common mode current as flowing on the outside of coax? Why does it matter which part of the metal shield the current flows in, and how do we know it's the outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common mode current occurs when current in the shield flows in a direction common with current in the center conductor.  "Common mode current" is just a simple descriptive label to distinguish it from differental current.

Common mode current is caused by all kinds of things.  Irregularities in the coax is the least likely of those.  Imbalance in the antenna is a possible cause.  The most likely cause is interaction between the outside of the shield and part of the antenna and other metal objects near by.

Common mode current can be blocked by a balun, but also if you try to position the coax so that it is at right angles to the dipole in all planes in a volume within 2-3 wavelengths (near field) of the antenna, it also will reduce the common mode current.  (In other words, balance it geometrically against the antenna it is feeding.)

Remember, this is about radio and radio waves.  Those don't travel in wires all the time.  They try to escape.  Thinking about things like "voltage divider at the junction" is thinking in DC where the energy can't escape the wire so easily and all the currents will sum up.   In RF with common mode current, they won't because some of the energy escapes before it gets to the junction.  After all, you are feeding an antenna, you are *trying* to make the energy escape, and we do our best to try to make it escape through the antenna, but it's frequently just as happy escaping along the length of the coax if we give it the opportunity.

Why do hams use a choke at the feed point?  Because this is one of the best places to block common mode current.  The choke can be almost anywhere along the coax, but the further from the feed point it is placed, the more coax is available to radiate through common mode current.  (There are nodal points on the coax where the choke would do nothing, and other points a (multiple of a) quarter wavelength away where it would have maximum effect.)

Common mode current isn't an "error condition".  Usually we try to avoid it, but sometimes we take advantage of it, and use the coax as an antenna.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you haven't really answered the question, CM current is a term used to describe the normally unwanted current that can exist in a differential system. Using that term to describe current in a single wire doesn't make sense. The outside of the braid of coax isn't part of a differential system with two wires with equal and opposite voltage and current.

Comment: You are correct -- common mode current isn't in a single wire.  It's only in coax and other transmission lines.  Without the center conductor, the current on the outside of the shield is uninteresting.  You are wrong in thinking that the outside and inside of the braid can be "separated" when thinking about coax.

Comment: There's some sloppy language here that I want to clear up with respect to "voltage divider".  In a DC system, current is considered to be constant in a wire.  This is true in an RF system too, as long as the "wire" is a transmission line like coax, and the current is all differential mode.  If there is common mode current in addition to the differential current, then the current will not be constant in the wire, as a portion of the common mode will radiate out of the wire along its entire length, and all the DC assumptions break, including those associated with voltage dividers.

Comment: You only think I didn't answer the question because you seem to insist that common mode current is special, and somehow different than the definition I put in the first paragraph of my answer.  I did answer the question, several times, and from several viewpoints.  The problem is that you have a preconceived notion of how this works and what it means that is apparent in the misconceptions in your question statement.  If you want to understand this, you have to recognize those misconceptions and release them.

Comment: user10489 Thanks for all your input so far, everything you are saying makes sense. But, what you are saying is exactly why i posted this question. Your comment "Common mode current occurs when current in the shield flows in a direction common with current in the center conductor" this is only true for the current on the inside of the shield, current on the outside is not part of the differential circuit inside the coax.

Comment: user10489 While it may be a simple descriptive term which can describe a very real condition, for example RF current induced by radiation from a nearby antenna, it isn't the correct term as common mode is normally associated with a differential system with two wires or terminals, and it doesn't make sense to use this to describe current which isn't part of a differential system.

Comment: The definition of common mode current I gave is always true, not conditionally true.  It is conditional if common mode current exists in a particular situation, but the term still has the same meaning.  Common mode current exists (or doesn't) in transmission lines; outside of that context, it isn't interesting.  It *should not* exist in differential systems that are functioning as differential systems (although it might).

Comment: The fact that common mode current is between the outside of the shield and the center conductor is how it manifests.  It's existence in the outside of the shield vs. just conducted in the shield is irrelevant.   In fact, "outside of the shield" is also an oversimplification, because skin depth requires it to actually be deeper than that, and the little tiny strands in the shield aren't really all that thick.

Comment: These last two comments of yours captures the heart of the issue as it is understood practically. Insofar as any antenna system is a non-ideal compromise, and the techniques developed to handle this fact.

Comment: Radiation from the antenna can also induce current in the outer shield. So a balun at the radio end of the feedline, not just the antenna end, can also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

RF Current on the outside of a coax will radiate an EM field.  You can test the amount of this EM with an RF field strength held up next to a coax at various locations along its length, and testing with and without a choke balun to an asymmetric antenna.  Any EM field radiating from a feed line is energy not radiating from the antenna (conservation laws), which is usually undesirable.

According to Maxwell, RF magnetic field generation is only possible if the vector sum of all currents on the coax (both “outside” and “inside”) are non-zero, thus a common mode current.

Comment: Everyone seems to be missing the point i am trying to make in the question, yes, induced RF in the outside of coax is real, but that too isn't a common mode mechanism. CM current is a term used to describe the normally unwanted current that can exist in a differential system. Using that term to describe current in a single wire doesn't make sense. The outside of the braid of coax isn't part of a differential system with two wires with equal and opposite voltage and current.

Comment: The only thing EM fields care about is the vector sum of all the currents, whether there is one conductor, or one hundred, and whether any or none are differential.   One usually only cares about common mode current on a feed line because it might generate an external EM field.

Comment: Common mode current describes the mode of operation of transmission line where a portion of the current is not differential and the fields fail to cancel, so that it radiates.  Sloppy language (and thinking) considers this to be only the current on the shield that radiates, but really it's an operation mode for the transmission line, and describes a situation where net current (across insulated wires) is non-zero.

Comment: It's not that common mode an differental mode  current can't exist in a single wire, it's that it just isn't *interesting*.     In a single wire (or piece of metal), common mode current is just current, and differental mode current is called eddy currents.

Comment: @Andrew I think one of the problems with your understanding is that there are rarely, in practice, "two wires with equal and opposite voltage and current" in any practical antenna system. CM problems arise precisely because real conductors under real situations behave in a very measurable manner.  We can describe typical aspects of this phenomena in a number of ways, but engineers and amateurs alike are also very interested in mitigation because the phenomena are so common (no pun intended). But $I1 \neq I2$ just... happens. A lot.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's perspective, i accepted user10489's answer, in part because of the first paragraph, and the comment " In a single wire (or piece of metal), common mode current is just current". And i was fully aware that CM current on the outside of coax isn't the only current that can radiate. But i think that using the term common mode in this instance is really stretching the meaning, and in my opinion this is sloppy thinking. I do appreciate all the comments and answers, i think the down vote for my question is a bit childish, but hey, as already mentioned it isn't a perfect world !

Comment: Saying "calling this common mode is stretching it" is like saying "I don't know why you call that red, it looks green to me."